# Installing Ubuntu after deleting Windows 8 - can it be installed in EFI (gpt) mode?

Tags: system-installation, format

I want to delete Windows 8 and want to install Ubuntu, but somebody told me that my hard disk needs to be in gpt mode and that I have to convert the hard drive to mbr. I don't want to convert or format the whole hard disk. What do I have to do?

Comment: There is no need to format the whole disk - installing Ubuntu in EFI (gpt) mode is supported out-of-the-box, as well as installing it in legacy BIOS (mbr) mode.

Comment: Sir I have deleted windows 8 , while installing windows 7 .now it is showing that you have gpt format windows 7 cannot be installed.now I am frustrated.can I install Linux , which version and how?

Comment: Sir my bios is legacy and uefi both but I have selected legacy. Tell me what to do next?

Answer (score 0):

If your BIOS is Legacy, then format your Hard Drive as `MBR for BIOS` or `MBR for BIOS/UEFI`. If it is UEFI, format your Hard Drive as `GPT for UEFI.`

Comment: You might wish to avoid "UEFI Safe mode" if you're interested in running e.g. Virtualbox and/or Nvidia drivers.

Comment: @Hannu You mean "Secure Boot"?

Comment: Typing this from memory, sorry unsure of the exact phrases.